# Setting character spacing with PDFBox

Tags: java, pdf, pdf-generation, pdfbox

I'm currently using Java and the PDFBox library to create some PDFs on the fly.

I need to be able to set the character spacing/tracking of some text but can't seem to figure it out.

It looks as there is a method to do so : http://ci.apache.org/projects/pdfbox/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/pdfbox/util/operator/SetCharSpacing.html

But I'm not quite sure how to apply this in the situation.

```
cs.beginText();
cs.setFont( font, fontSize );
cs.setNonStrokingColor(color);
cs.moveTextPositionByAmount(position[0], position[1]);
cs.drawString(text);
cs.endText();
```

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to do it the hard way, because the "Tc" operator isn't supported by the PDPageContentStream class:

```
cs.appendRawCommands("0.25 Tc\n");
```

The SetCharSpacing method you mentioned is for parsing existing PDFs.

PS: don't forget to call close after finishing writing to the content stream!

PPS: `setCharacterSpacing()` is available in version 2.0.4 and higher.

Comment: Thanks for the speedy response, let me try this out! :)

Comment: Perfect - why isn't this stuff easier to find?! Thanks again.

Comment: We've put only the main operators in the PDPageContentStream class... the "exotic" operators can still be used as described. If you think it would benefit others, make a request in PDFBox JIRA and I'll include it for the next release.

Comment: This way, is 'appendRawCommands(java.lang.String)' is deprecated' already. New version way is `contentStream.setCharacterSpacing(10);`

Answer (score 0):

You can change the number `10` as you like to have more character spacing.

```java
contentStream.setCharacterSpacing(10);
```

Comment: As @Tilman mentions in his answer, `setCharacterSpacing()` is available in version 2.0.4 and higher.

Comment: Yes, but no longer `"0.25 Tc\n"` anymore, it should be an integer or float