# How to set letter-spacing in Apache PDFBox 2.0?

Tags: apache, character, pdfbox, spacing, letter-spacing

is it possible to define letter-spacing in Apache PDFBox 2.0? As addRawCommands Method is deprecated now, I'm looking for an alternative method.

Thank you!

In the following question the user has answered with addRawCommands, but I'm not using version 1.8.*:
[Setting character spacing with PDFBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30144632/setting-character-spacing-with-pdfbox)

Comment: like I said in the other issue... make a request in JIRA.